# Problems with cpanel: SSL Configuration

Tags: ssl, cpanel

So... I have my SSL certificate (Comodo, btw). I can't install it on cpanel.
I've been told that it can be solved easily with the 'instal ssl' but I don't have that option.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install the SSL certificate from your

> cPanel -> SSL/TLS -> Install and Manage SSL for your site (HTTPS)

If you do not have this option in your cPanel, you can try changing your cPanel theme from the Switch Theme menu and try again.

In case it still does not show, I am afraid that your only option left would be to provide the SSL to your hosting company, so they install it for you from WHM.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing. Apparentily that option is not free on my hosting plan.

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Please forward your SSL certificate file to your hosting provider. They will install it for your through WHM root user.